# Drawing 2D grid in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to get a 2D grid using matlab with *x >= -1* and *y <= 1* with step size of 0.1
But I'm getting 3D grid with no proper step sizes. Any ideas?

My code:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:5, 0:0.1:1);
surf(x,y)
```

Comment: you question is not clear to me. What do you mean by a 2D "grid"?, can you give an example of a "grid"? (FYI in matlab the command `grid` plots grid lines on a plot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just want to plot a bunch of 2D points?  You use [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).  Using your example, you would take your `x,y` points and simply put dot markers for each point.  Convert them into 1D arrays first before you do this:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:5, 0:0.1:1);
X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);
plot(X,Y,'b.');
xlabel('X'); % // Label the X and Y axes
ylabel('Y');
```

This is what I get:

[image]

---

## Edit based on comments

If you want to rotate this grid by an angle, you would use a rotation matrix and multiply this with each pair of `(x,y)` co-ordinates.  If you recall from linear algebra, to rotate a point counter-clockwise, you would perform the following matrix multiplication:

```
[x'] = [cos(theta) -sin(theta)][x]
[y']   [sin(theta)  cos(theta)][y]
```

`x,y` are the original co-ordinates while `x',y'` are the output co-ordinates after rotation of an angle `theta`.  If you want to rotate -30 degrees (which is 30 degrees clockwise), you would just specify `theta = -30 degrees`.  Bear in mind that `cos` and `sin` take in their angles as **radians**, so this is actually `-pi/6` in radians.  What you need to do is place each of your points into a 2D matrix.  You would then use the rotation matrix and apply it to each point.  This way, you're vectorizing the solution instead of... say... using a `for` loop.  Therefore, you would do this:

```
theta = -pi/6; % // Define rotation angle
rot = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)]; %// Define rotation matrix
rotate_val = rot*[X Y].'; %// Rotate each of the points
X_rotate = rotate_val(1,:); %// Separate each rotated dimension
Y_rotate = rotate_val(2,:);
plot(X_rotate, Y_rotate, 'b.'); %// Show the plot
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
```

This is what I get:

[image]

If you wanted to perform other transformations, like scaling each axis, you would just multiply either the `X` or `Y` co-ordinates by an appropriate scale:

```
X_scaled = scale_x*X;
Y_scaled = scale_y*Y;
```

`X_scaled` and `Y_scaled` are the scaled versions of your co-ordinates, with `scale_x` and `scale_y` are the scales in each dimension you want.  If you wanted to translate the co-ordinates, you would add or subtract each of the dimensions by some number:

```
X_translate = X + X_shift; %// Or -
Y_translate = Y + Y_shift; %// Or -
```

`X_translate` and `Y_translate` are the translated co-ordinates, while `X_shift` and `Y_shift` are the amount of shifts you want per dimension.  Note that you either do `+` or `-`, depending on what you want.

Comment: Could you give me ideas for performing spatial transformations using this grid? Like performing rotation by -30 degree?

Comment: @James - Yeah, for each point in your grid, you should just apply a rotation matrix to this grid.  I'll update my post.

Comment: You're awesome! I'm getting a lot to learn from your answers.